# Visual Basic Image Recognition

Tags: c#, image, vba, key, ocr

First of all, I know that VB can do an OCR to turn image(which includes text) into text, but is it possible to recognize an Image and maybe initialize an action?
 For example I got an Image of an Arrow here:

[image]

Can VB recognize this kind of arrow and do a

```
Sendkey.key("{RIGHT}")
```

When the Arrow shows up on the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it is not trivial. The OpenCV (Open Computer Vision) library can do these things. It makes use of classifier files which is the output of "training" the system to recognize objects. If there are no existing classifiers for arrows you would have to train your own.
There is an open source implementation for .Net that makes it much more approachable to use:
http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Emgu_CV

Comment: I guess you will be my answer for the question :D